# How do I remove just one element from my array based on its value if there are more than one of each value

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I remove just one element from an array based on value if there are multiples of each value. The array is a deck of cards btw.

Comment: Hi, Colin. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is unclear. "*The array is a deck of cards*" is not enough information to understand the issue you're facing. Please take some time to read the help page, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know where it is in the array, you can find out using `findIndex`:

```
const index = theArray.findIndex(entry => entry.property === value);
```

That returns the index of the **first** match, or -1 if no match was found. Then you can remove it either by using `splice` to modify the original array:

```
theArray.splice(index, 1);
```

...or by creating a new array omitting that element:

```
theArray = theArray.filter((e, i) => i !== index);
```

Live Example:

```js
let theArray = [
  {suit: "Diamonds", number: 1},
  {suit: "Clubs", number: 7},
  {suit: "Spades", number: 6},
  {suit: "Clubs", number: 1}
];

// Find and remove the first Club
const index = theArray.findIndex(entry => entry.suit === "Clubs");
if (index !== -1) {
    theArray.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("Updated array:", theArray);
} else {
    console.log("Not found");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Another approach is to just use `filter` to create a new array, with a flag telling yourself whether you've already found and removed the item:

```
let found = false;
theArray = theArray.filter(entry => found || !(found = entry.property === value));
```

Live Example:

```js
let theArray = [
    {suit: "Diamonds", number: 1},
    {suit: "Clubs", number: 7},
    {suit: "Spades", number: 6},
    {suit: "Clubs", number: 1}
];

// Find and remove the first Club
let found = false;
theArray = theArray.filter(entry => found || !(found = entry.suit === "Clubs"));
console.log("Updated array:", theArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```